# IPFS-Liteを使ってアプリケーションの作成

Tags: go, ipfs

IPFS-Liteを使って、アプリケーションを作成しようと思っています。
goをインストールして、下記のコマンドを実行しました。
go mod init example.com/ipfs-lite
go get github.com/hsanjuan/ipfs-lite
その後、IPFS-Liteを用いて、ローカルノードにファイルを追加して、CIDを出力する下記のようなコードを書いたところエラーが表示されました。

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"

    ipfslite "github.com/hsanjuan/ipfs-lite"
)

func main() {
    // IPFS-Liteノードを作成する
    node, err := ipfslite.New(context.Background(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // ファイルを読み込む
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("test.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // ファイルを追加する
    c, err := node.Add(bytes.NewReader(data))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // CIDを出力する
    fmt.Printf("Added file with CID: %s\n", c.String())
}
```

エラーの内容は下記です。

```
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:14:50: not enough arguments in call to ipfslite.New
        have (context.Context, nil)
        want (context.Context, datastore.Batching, blockstore.Blockstore, host.Host, "github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p/core/routing".Routing, *ipfslite.Config)
./main.go:26:12: assignment mismatch: 2 variables but node.Add returns 1 value
./main.go:26:21: not enough arguments in call to node.Add
        have (*bytes.Reader)
        want (context.Context, "github.com/ipfs/go-ipld-format".Node)
```

どのようにしたらうまくいくか分からず質問させていただきました。

Comment: https://github.com/hsanjuan/ipfs-lite/blob/master/examples/litepeer/litepeer.go を参考にしてみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
上のコードを参考にして、書いてみます。